# edit 'value px' in elemtn.style.width px using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I got a function which gets the size from the user and creates the div, but I'm not sure how to express the size in front of px.

```
function createDiv(size) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("box");
  div.style.width = `${size} px`;
  div.style.height = `${size} px`;
  console.log(size);

  return div;
}
```

It works if I input the size as 75px:

```
function createDiv(size) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("box");
  div.style.width = "75px";
  div.style.height = "75px";
  console.log(size);

  return div;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space between the value and `px`, it should be like this: `${size}px`.

```js
function createDiv(size) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("box");
  div.style.width = `${size}px`;
  div.style.height = `${size}px`;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

createDiv(100);
```

```css
.box {
  background: lawngreen;
}
```